# The square root of 2 is irrational. A proof variant?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers, education, plane-geometry

Does the following provide a proper proof for the irrationality of $\sqrt2$? It might be a good prelude to the Pythagorean theorem and real numbers.

---

We know that the hypotenuse of a right isosceles triangle is $b=\sqrt{2}a$, where $a$ is the side length. To see this, we divide the area of a square into two right triangles: $$a^2 = \frac{1}{2}b\cdot \frac{b}{2}+ \frac{1}{2}b\cdot \frac{b}{2}.$$

Let us assume that the side length $a$ is the smallest possible integer such that the hypotenuse $b$ is also an integer. But if $b=\sqrt{2}a$, then we may multiply both sides by $(\sqrt2-1)$ and have $(2a-b)=\sqrt{2}(b-a)$ that represents a right isosceles triangle with the integer valued side length and hypotenuse that are smaller than $a$ and $b$. Thus, there is no integer $a$ such that $b=\sqrt{2}a$ is also an integer.

Comment: Looks like this geometric proof: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Geometric_proof

Comment: @lhf Apparently it's the same thing in another, possibly simplified way.

Comment: The geometry is totally irrelevant here. If you simply omit all mention of triangles and start  with $\sqrt 2=b/a$ as usual the rest of the proof works.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oh yes, very true. On the other hand, the tringle stuff shows how there is a geometric (true) length $\sqrt{2}$ that is to be investigated. Maybe this has some educational value before student are introduced to the Pythagorean theorem - and the Pythagorean tragedy of irrational ratios.

Comment: It *is* important before talking about $\sqrt 2$ to have a good reason why we think $\sqrt 2$ should exist at all.  After all there is no reason to assume $orange juice + 1$, $\frac 10$, $\sqrt {-1}$ or $turtles \times blueberries$ exist so why should $\sqrt 2$?  A vague concept of continuum is pretty important but vague and abstract and hard for a student to grasp what a big deal it is.  Isosceles right triangles make it pragmatic (although it's really just the concept the geometry is measurable which is just the concept of continuum made plain).

Comment: It's not a new proof, but I don't see the reason for the downvotes. We have plenty of questions about proving that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational, such as [Prove that $2^{1/2}$ is irrational](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/944992/139123), but none of the ones I found take a geometric approach. Yes, Wikipedia has such a proof; this question is a good way to link to that.

Comment: @DavidK Now I found this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2316991/sqrt2-proved-irrational-by-denominator-descent-on-sqrt-2-1?rq=1

Comment: Yes, that's another non-geometric proof. I think it's good to link to these for comparison.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich . In  the book A History Of Mathematics by Merzbakh & Boyer they suggest the Golden Ratio $\phi$ might have been the first known irrational by the method in this Q:  We have $\phi=\frac {1}{\phi -1}$. If $\phi=\frac {a}{b}$ with $a,b\in \Bbb N$  and the least possible $a$, then $ a>b$ (as $\phi>1$), but then $\phi=\frac  {1}{a/b-1}=\frac  {b}{a-b}$ with a smaller numerator.